# Webpack looking for changes only in specific files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, sass

I'm using Webpack in my project for watching .scss and .ts files.

I have folder with scss files.

Here is structure:

[image: Screen]

When I edit something in app.scss file, Webpack watching for changes and recompile.

When I edit something inside includes folder, Webpack does not recompile.

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

let dist = 'wwwroot'

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/js/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, dist),
        filename: 'js/[name].min.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/, 
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: { configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json') }
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            includePaths: ["./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: 'img/',
                            publicPath: '../images/',
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            publicPath: '../fonts/',
                        }
                    }

                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
                options: {
                    name: "[name].[ext]",
                    outputPath: 'img/',
                    publicPath: '../images/',
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "jquery.validation": "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(dist, {}),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].min.css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css",
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: './src/img',
                to: 'images',
                toType: 'dir'
            }
        ]),
    ],
}
```

I can't understand why it's not working with files inside includes folder.
Where is my problem?

Comment: I think it has something to do with: `includePaths: ["./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"]`

Comment: I need to add path to scss folder to include path? @FrankerZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the sass folder to your include options:

```
options: {
    includePaths: ["./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss", "path-to-your-sass-folder"]
}
```